# How do we generate load in the queue using selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We are trying to generate videos (video streaming via Youtube URL's) in the queue. Some of the users will be watching the videos in FIFO Format so we would like to know the process where we can push the videos to the queue (to generate load) using selenium.

The queue type is amazon SQS system.

Answer (score 0):

If it's load testing what you are trying to archive then you need jmeter, checking [Amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests.html) it seems possible to send http request via API call.

[Here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211732/how-to-integrate-jmeter-with-selenium-webdriver-for-load-testing) there is explained how to integrate jmeter with webdriver